# The marker of "details" tag hides from me. How to avoid it?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a details tag that should open on the right side. The following works:

```css
details, summary, form {
  display: inline;
}

summary {
  /* just a matter of personal taste */
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

summary::marker {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  Color<details><summary>*</summary>

    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="color" value="red" checked>
      <label for="choice1">Red</label>

      <input type="radio" id="choice2" name="color" value="yellow">
      <label for="choice2">Yellow</label>

      <input type="radio" id="choice3" name="color" value="green">
      <label for="choice3">Green</label>
    <form>
  </details>
</div>
```

However, I want the asterisk to be the contents of the `marker` and not the `summary`. The following doesn't work:

```css
/* The marker hides from me. */
  details, summary, form {
  display: inline;
}

summary::marker {
  content: '*';
}
```

```html
<div>
  Color<details><summary></summary>

    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="color" value="red" checked>
      <label for="choice1">Red</label>

      <input type="radio" id="choice2" name="color" value="yellow">
      <label for="choice2">Yellow</label>

      <input type="radio" id="choice3" name="color" value="green">
      <label for="choice3">Green</label>
    <form>
  </details>
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set:

```css
summary {
 font-size: 0
}
summary::after {
 font-size: 1rem;
 content: "*";
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I want. Isn't it possible to use the default `::marker` and not `::after` instead?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/explaining-the-details-and-summary-elements--cms-21999

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

> The `::marker` CSS pseudo-element selects the marker box of a list
> item, which typically contains a bullet or number. It works on any
> element or pseudo-element set to display: list-item, such as the `<li>`
> and `<summary>` elements.

Try removing the `display: inline` from `summary` element.

Look at the user agent stylesheet generated: You can see that `display: list-item` is added by the browser by default for the summary tags. Overriding them would stop it's normal function.

I have also moved the `form` element outside the `details` markup so that it is visible.

[image]

```css
/* The marker hides from me. */

details,
form {
  display: inline;
}

summary::marker {
  content: '*';
}
```

```html
<div>Color<details>
    <summary></summary>


  </details>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="color" value="red" checked>
    <label for="choice1">Red</label>

    <input type="radio" id="choice2" name="color" value="yellow">
    <label for="choice2">Yellow</label>

    <input type="radio" id="choice3" name="color" value="green">
    <label for="choice3">Green</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The radio buttons are shown below the asterisk, so currently it is not what I need. Here is a quote from my question: "I want to create a details tag that should open **on the right side.**"

Comment: Isn't the main question title your focus: `The marker of “details” tag hides from me. How to avoid it?`

Comment: Without that you cannot even see the `::marker` tag in the first place. I would suggest you to use a new `div` and then align the two `div`s with `inline-block` or `flex` or whatever. Even `inline`.